# ko.computed on an ko.observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to use a computed to calculate the total of some product.

```
function productViewModel(){

    self = this;
    function productModel(data)
    {
        var self=this;
        self.id=ko.observable(data.id);
        self.codigo=ko.observable(data.codigo);
        self.recurso=ko.observable(data.recurso);
        self.unidad=ko.observable(data.unidad);
        self.precio_unitario=ko.observable(0);
        self.cantidad=ko.observable(0);
        self.total=ko.computed(function()
            {
                return self.precio_unitario()*self.cantidad(); 
            },productModel); 
    }

    self.products = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addProduct = function(product)
    {
        self.products.push(new productModel(product));
    };
    self.removeProduct = function()
    {
        self.products.remove(this);
    };

}

orden = new productViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(orden);
```

But when `precio_unitario` and `cantidad` are changed. `total` doesn't update.

Answer (score 3):

```
function productModel(data)
{
    var self=this;
    ...
    self.total=ko.computed(function()
        {
            return self.precio_unitario()*self.cantidad(); 
        },this); 
}
```

You should be binding the ko.computed to `this` not to the function.  You want it to be bound to the object thats created, not to the constructor, which won't have those properties on it.  Since you're using self, this will actually be taken care of by default, and if you like you can omit the second argument entirely.

Within the constructor function, `this` or `self` will refer to the object that is created when you use the `new` operator.  So all the properties will be created on that object.

Comment: +1, but because he is already storing a reference to `this` in `self`, is there any need to bind at all?

Comment: @Robbie good call.  I just saw the wrong thing bound and figured I'd replace it with the right thing, but removing it altogether should be fine

Comment: @kadosh if you're still having issues it may be with your bindings,not your view-model set up.  Are you positive that the view model components are actually changing, and that you've bound to total correctly?  Nested stuff like this can get tricky with the bindings (though it looks like your comment is gone now.  Solved?)

Answer (score 2):

`self = this;` should be `var self = this;`; otherwise you're overwriting the global `self`. Also take out `,productModel` on the computed; it's not necessary.

Important parts:

```
function productViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    function productModel(data) {
        var self = this;
        ...
        self.total = ko.computed(function() {
            return self.precio_unitario()*self.cantidad(); 
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Also it's important make sure you're always using the correct format for writing to observables. It should be `self.catidad(newValue);` and not `self.catidad = newValue;`

Comment: Cool. BTW, when you have `var self = that = this;`, you are setting a global `that`.

Comment: Excellent point, I should have commented that, but it was more a short visual for Kadosh.  There are more nuances that occur in other blocks, but I hope he can understand what's happening